# How to replace a struct property with one that needs to retain a property of that old property?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have written some serial protocol code:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum State {
    WAIT_DLE,
    WAIT_STX,
    WAIT_DLE_OR_BYTE { payload: Vec<u8> },
    WAIT_DLE_OR_ETX { payload: Vec<u8> },
    WAIT_CRC { payload: Vec<u8>, crc: u32, remaining: usize },
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct Decoder {
    state: State,
    decoded: u64,
    unstuffing_errors: u64,
    crc_errors: u64
}

impl Decoder {
    fn new() -> Decoder {
        Decoder { 
            state: State::WAIT_DLE,
            decoded: 0,
            unstuffing_errors: 0,
            crc_errors: 0,        
        }
    }

    fn decode_byte(&mut self, byte: u8) -> Option<Vec<u8>> {
        self.state = match self.state {
            State::WAIT_DLE => match byte {
                DLE => State::WAIT_STX,
                _ => State::WAIT_DLE
            },
            State::WAIT_STX => match byte {
                STX => State::WAIT_DLE_OR_BYTE { payload: Vec::<u8>::new() },
                _ => State::WAIT_DLE
            },
            State::WAIT_DLE_OR_BYTE { mut payload } => match byte {
                DLE => State::WAIT_DLE_OR_ETX { payload },
                b => {
                    payload.push(b);
                    State::WAIT_DLE_OR_BYTE { payload }
                }
            },
            ...
```

The error is:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.state.payload` as enum variant `WAIT_CRC` which is behind a mutable reference
  --> common/src/dlecrc32.rs:46:28
   |
46 |         self.state = match self.state {
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^ help: consider borrowing here: `&self.state`
...
55 |             State::WAIT_DLE_OR_BYTE { mut payload } => match byte {
   |                                       ----------- data moved here
...
62 |             State::WAIT_DLE_OR_ETX { mut payload } => match byte {
   |                                      ----------- ...and here
...
73 |             State::WAIT_CRC { payload, mut crc, remaining } => {
   |                               ------- ...and here
   |
   = note: move occurs because these variables have types that don't implement the `Copy` trait
```

Its advice to use a `&self.state` reference is not helpful, as many paths need to rip the `payload: Vec<u8>` out of the old state and put it into the new state.  (Copying the vector's contents would be wasteful, as its old owner is being dropped.)

I can fix the problem by using `mem::swp()` to temporarily put a dummy value into `state` while dismembering the old state:

```
fn decode_byte(&mut self, byte: u8) -> Option<Vec<u8>> {
    let mut swapped_state = State::WAIT_DLE;
    mem::swap(&mut self.state, &mut swapped_state);

    self.state = match swapped_state {
```

This is wasteful, as it is copying the bytes of `self.state` when that is not required.

Another unattractive solution is to make the `State` properties properties of the `Decoder`, turning the `State` enum into a C-style enum.

Is there a way to let the compiler accept that as I'm assigning to `self.state`, it's OK for me to dismember the old `self.state`?

Comment: `mem::replace()` (not `mem::swap()` is the correct way. But the compiler is also right: what if `payload.push()` panics? The value will be left uninitialized.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman The compiler also complains about the non-mutable `State::WAIT_CRC { payload, mut crc, remaining } => {` so I'm guessing that its objecting to something other than the `payload.push()`.  (Note: that `WAIT_CRC` branch is beyond the end of the code snippet.)

Comment: I didn't say it is concerned by that, it doesn't understand your code to that level of detail. But it is concerned with the language rules, and those are designed to prevent that.